# Why should I use a service in this case?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I'm following this basic tutorial:
http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/

As you can see, it basically does the following (correct me if i'm wrong, please):

- Once MainActivity is launched, sets an Alarm for a specific date and time.
- As soon as this date and time is reached, it starts an intent to `MyReceiver.class`

**First stop.**: `MyReceiver` is extending `BroadcastReceiver`. Is it possible to start an Intent to a normal Activity?

- BroadcastReceiver just triggers a new Intent to open a Service, which just shows a Notification.

**Second stop.**: Same as before: BroadcastReceiver, can only launch Intents which are Services? Or can it launch normal activities? Why do I even have to call any new intent? Why can't I just do the job in BroadcastReceiver (like downloading some content over internet)?

I'm a bit new about Services, so I'm sorry if I said something extremly weird.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I just do the job in BroadcastReceiver (like downloading
>   some content over internet)?

As per Android Documentation Broadcast receivers onReceive method is called on Main Thread so you can not perform downloading task in onReceive.Since it will freeze the UI and may throw exception in 3.0 and above version.

If you want to perform download,then the best bet would be to trigger IntentService inside onReceive ( IntentService by default runs on background thread.)

Comment: IntentService, is the same as a normal Intent which it's class extends Service and is launched by `context.startService(intent)`? Or maybe is it some special kind of service, which is totally different?

Comment: The only difference is it runs on background thread and you have to call onHandleIntent.

Comment: Oh, then I've to use IntentService for sure, to perform networking actions.

Answer (score 1):

`BroadcastReceiver` is just a means to do anything you want upon receiving a broadcast.

A `Service` is something that won't easily be killed by the Android OS unlike an `Activity`. `Service` has no GUI though.

Answer (score 1):

BroadcastReceivers can launch anything you want (Activities, Services) with an intent.

The reason you dont want to stuff in a BroadcastReceiver is because they only live so long where as a service runs until you tell it to stop.

If you are doing polling or something you really dont need a BroadcastReceiver and you can just use a service (`IntentService` specifically) with your alarm manager. An IntentService only runs a long as it has something to do meaning it will stop itself unlike a normal service where you have to stop it when its done.